# Custom attribute value gets change through jquery but the change doesn't show up in rendered html

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup-balloons, balloon-tip

I am using balloon.css for tooltip.

The text of tooltip on element comes from custom attribute 'data-balloon'.

I want to load text of tooltip dynamically.

I can change it through jquery but new text doesn't get rendered on displayed html.

Here is my code :

HTML Code Mention Below:

```
<div id="instruction_div_main" data-balloon="Original text"></div>
```

Jquery Code Mention Below:

```
alert($("#instruction_div_main").attr("data-balloon"));
// alert shows "Original text"

$("#instruction_div_main").attr("data-balloon","New Text");

alert($("#instruction_div_main").attr("data-balloon"));
// alert shows "New text"
```

But now when i hover on that div, It doesn't show new text, It still shows "Original text"

Why it is so and please correct me where i am wrong.

FYI : I am facing similar issue for title attribute.

**Update **

I am showing that tooltip on some icon that is displayed in jquery ui dialog. There is back button on that dialog that hide icon and show some radio buttons. And when select any radio button, icon gets shown up again, radio button disappears. And this time tooltip of icon should be new one. I am using above code but the original text is shows up where i can see that the attribute values has been changed but not getting rendered on icon tooltip.

[image]

Comment: You need to reinitialize the tooltip after changing attribute...

Comment: I am not sure how but FYI  i am not using tooltip plugin here.

Comment: I just tried it... And on my side, it shows «New Text».

Comment: How are you showing the tooltip, can you post that part of code?

Comment: @anu: See here : https://github.com/kazzkiq/balloon.css/blob/master/balloon.css

Comment: @Anjum: Have you loaded jQuery in order to use `$("#instruction_div_main").attr("data-balloon","New Text");` ??

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - yes i have used jquery

Comment: check your DOM using dev tools to see whether the attribute is actually getting updated or not because it is [working for me](https://jsbin.com/raxuvayege/edit?html,js,output). Also check for any errors in console

Comment: I have check DOM by inspecting elements. But it is not getting changed in html there either

Comment: I have loaded jquery file because my jquery dialog box is show up fine with no issue.

Comment: There is no errors on console. Its all clear there too.

Comment: I have updated my question, please have a look at it

Comment: Check for some mistyping on `data-balloon` in the attribute change function... Since your example here may not be a cut and paste... Maybe you typed `data-ballon` or something. ;)

Comment: If its not getting updated in DOM then you need debug the code where you are updating the attribute. Put a breakpoint there and check whether that part of code is getting executed or not. And is it is executed then how it is getting reset again

Comment: This is really very confusing because i have executed alter statement and in alerts i am getting updated values but when i hover over that element, still old tooltip/title

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look attached snippet.

```js
alert($("#instruction_div_main").attr("data-balloon"));
// alert shows "Original text"

$("#instruction_div_main").attr("data-balloon","New Text");
$("#instruction_div_main").html("New Text");
$("#instruction_div_main").attr("title","New Text");
alert($("#instruction_div_main").attr("data-balloon"));
// alert shows "New text"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="instruction_div_main" title="Original text" data-balloon="Original text">Original text</div>
```